# The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined - why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am submitting a form that contains a user id and a pipe-delimited set of numbers.

The model looks like this:

```
public class SeasonPassData
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string SpaceNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

That is getting handed off to this controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SignUp(SeasonPassData data)
{
    var user = db.Users.Find(data.UserID);
    List<SeasonPass> passes = new List<SeasonPass>();

    char[] delimiter = { '|' };
    var numbers = data.SpaceNumbers.Split(delimiter).Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
    foreach(int number in numbers)
    {
        passes.Add(new SeasonPass { SpaceNumber=number, User = user });
    }
    passes.ForEach(p => db.SeasonPasses.Add(p));
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Confirmation", "Home");
}
```

And should be creating and saving SeasonPasses:

```
public class SeasonPass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SpaceNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

However, this - `passes.ForEach(p => db.SeasonPasses.Add(p));` keeps raiding this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The relationship between the two objects
>   cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext
>   objects.

**How do I fix that?**

---

I tried it with these changes based on a comment. It still doesn't seem to work...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SignUp(SeasonPassData data)
{
    using(var context = new TTUContext())
    {
        var user = context.Users.Find(data.UserID);
        List<SeasonPass> passes = new List<SeasonPass>();

        char[] delimiter = { '|' };
        var numbers = data.SpaceNumbers.Split(delimiter).Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
        foreach (int number in numbers)
        {
            passes.Add(new SeasonPass { SpaceNumber = number, User = user });
        }
        foreach (var pass in passes)
        {
            context.SeasonPasses.Add(pass);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Confirmation", "Home");
}
```

Comment: What is `db`? Is that an `ObjectContext`?

Comment: @DaveZych yes. Sorry for not including that.

Comment: Interesting...I wonder if the lambda is newing up your context or something?  What happens if you just do a 'regular' foreach loop and/or put a using{} block with your context?

Comment: @BobMac Just posted the changes with your recommendations - still no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: Mind blown my friend. Two thoughts, add `public int UserID { get; set; }` to `SeasonPass` and use it to set the user relationship. If that doesn't work, have you tried restarting IIS? Perhaps something is stuck in EF's cache that is causing this odd behavior.

Comment: @JeremyCook Reset my computer, and cleaned and rebuilt the solution - no luck. Yeah - the good news is I don't have to use this model that often. I guess I'll just have to deal with the User_ID property. That worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that what you are doing does not work, but here is a way to sidestep the issue.

Add `public int UserID { get; set; }` to `SeasonPass` and set it to assign the relationship instead of setting `User`.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. it's a pain, but at least it works.